# How to split string condition on array with powershell script. Exporting SharePoint library data on csv file

Tags: sharepoint-designer, powershell, query-string, string, loop

i am trying export library data into CSV file. i had used string functionality on my script to get content. my script was working fine but i am getting output in single string (or) one column. My script and out as below.

## Script

```
$web = get-spweb "SiteURL"
$caseLib = $web.lists | where {$_.title -eq "Library"}

$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
$query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='LinkFilename'/><FieldRef Name='DocumentSetDescription'/><FieldRef Name='Party_x0020_Lookup'/><FieldRef Name='State_x0020_code'/><FieldRef Name='Case_x0020_Manager'/>"
$query.RowLimit=50000

do
{
    $caseLibItems=$caseLib.GetItems($query) 
    $query.ListItemCollectionPosition=$caseLibItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    $listItemsTotal = $caseLibItems.Count

    $x = 0
    for($x=0;$x -lt $listItemsTotal; $x++)
    {
        $Description = $caseLibItems[$x]["DocumentSetDescription"]
        $CaseManager = $caseLibItems[$x]["Case_x0020_Manager"]
    
        $str = ""
        if('$Description; $CaseManager' -ne $null)
        {
            $str = $caseLibItems[$x]["LinkFilename"].ToString() 
                + $Description 
                + $caseLibItems[$x]["Party_x0020_Lookup"].ToString() 
                + $caseLibItems[$x]["State_x0020_code"].ToString() 
                + $CaseManager 
        }
        else
        {
            $str = $caseLibItems[$x]["LinkFilename"].ToString()  
        }
        Write-Output $str | Out-File "C:\test.csv"  -Append
    }
} while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
       
Write-Host "Exiting"
```

### Output file in CSV

> XXXXX-2-AB-123,file was uploaded,country1,12345,xxxx@gmail.com
>
> XXXXX-3-CB-124,data received,country2,12365,xyzab@gmail.com
>
> XXXXX-8-AC-246,file mismatch uploaded,country1,12345,xxxx@gmail.com

I want to add headers on CSV and i want output file data below format on CSV file (Means, name content should come in one column, Description data should come in another column,Party lockup another column etc ).. How to split string in array.
If anyone had idea please share with updated powershell script

### Name            Description      Party Lookup      State code   Case Manager

> XXXXX-2-AB-123      file was uploaded      country1      12345
> xxxx@gmail.com
>
> XXXXX-3-CB-124    data received    country2  1236    xyzab@gmail.com
>
> XXXXX-8-AC-246   file mismatch uploaded  country1 12345
> xxxx@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Create your outfile first and add a header to it:

```
$outFile = New-Item "C:\test.csv" -ItemType file -Force
```

Note that -Force will cause the file to be overwritten each time.
Now add your header:

```
"Name,Description,Party Lookup,State code, Case Manager" | Out-File $outFile
```

You don't need $str just write your stuff out e.g.:

```
"$($caseLibItems[$x]["LinkFilename"].ToString()),$Description,$($caseLibItems[$x]["Party_x0020_Lookup"].ToString()),$($caseLibItems[$x]["State_x0020_code"].ToString()), $CaseManager" | Out-File $outFile -Append
```

For items that don't have all the values just add commas:

```
"$($caseLibItems[$x]["LinkFilename"].ToString()),,,," | Out-File $outFile -Append
```

Comment: Sorry, again i am getting output file same. Values are coming one column only. I need each header data need to another column. Means in "Name" column it should come "XXXXX-2-AB-123" and in "Description" need to come next column with data and etc. Column A = Name data, Column B= Description data, Column C= Party Lookup data etc. Hope you got my requirement. My final requirement is export all column data of SharePoint document library into CSV. Please help me with your updated code.

Comment: How are you opening your files? If they are comma separated then they will be in separate columns. Just make sure you import them correctly.